# What does the keyword " ret " do in x86 assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I'm a newbie in x86 assembly code and I came across a piece of code in a course I'm taking. The main purpose of this procedure is to loop through an array from the beginning and return the value of the first non-zero element. My question is why don't we need another " ret " in the " notfound " instruction or jump to " quit " like it did in the instruction " found "? Is it because eax always contains the return value that we want from the procedure? From what I understand, eax is just an accumulator register, right?

```
.386
.model flat

.data
;data labels does not have column
intArray SWORD 0,0,0,0,1,3,0,-34,-56,7,8

.code
main    proc
        mov ebx,OFFSET intArray
        mov ecx,LENGTHOF intArray

;instruction labels have columns
L1:
        cmp WORD PTR[ebx],0
        jnz found
        add ebx,2
        loop L1
        jmp notfound

found:
        movsx eax,WORD  PTR[ebx]
        jmp quit

notfound:
        mov eax,999999

quit:
        ret

main    endp
end     main
```

Shouldn't we add a " ret " or jump to " quit " in the " notfound " instruction as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Labels don't execute; they are convenience for the assembly programmer and the assembler.  They are removed/discarded from the machine code output of the assembler.  If you want to change the flow of control of the instruction stream that the processor will execute, you have to tell the processor by using assembly instructions that turn into machine code.  Otherwise, the processor will see the machine code as if assembly without labels.  So, since `quit:` stripped from the machine code, the processor never sees it, when it is running the code at `notfound:`.

Comment: Imagine the code without labels to see it from the processors point of view.  `jmp` and `jnz` then have an offset as the target rather than a label as the target.  The offset is the number of bytes forward or backward to identify the next instruction to run when a jump is taken.  The assembler uses labels to compute those offsets that are put as the `jmp` operand in the machine code.

Comment: Here `ret` is used to return to the caller.  It assumes a return address is on the top of the stack and moves that into the instruction pointer so as to discontinue the called function, and resume the suspended caller.

Comment: A more efficient way to write this would be to replace `jmp quit` with a `ret`.  (This is called a "tail duplication" optimization, giving the function two return paths, which actually saves code size because there's no epilogue. And `ret` is smaller than `jmp`).  But the code here is correct, so it's a good example of the fact that execution falls through labels.

Comment: What `ret` does in terms of the CPU is essentially `pop eip`. It takes the top dword off the stack and puts it into the `eip` register. Now you might think that's very dangerous and unreliable. And that's because it is.

Comment: That's not to say you shouldn't use it though. Just keep in mind that it's one of the reasons that buffer overflow vulnerabilities exist.

Answer (score 0):

After your `mov eax,999999` statement (which is the end of `notfound` label), it proceeds to `quit` label. No `jmp` is required in that the `ret` instruction is following the `mov eax,999999` instruction.

The reason there is a `jmp quit` before `notfound` label is because `ret` instruction is not the following instruction of the end of `found` label.

In other words, you will have to add a `jmp quit` when you add new stuff between `notfound` and `quit` labels.

Comment: Correct, but I think it's even clearer to say labels don't have "ends", they're zero-width just marking a single address, the boundary between two instructions, or the start of the instruction after.  The CPU doesn't even see labels when it's executing machine code.  (Basic block have ends.  The block starting at `notfound:` is just the `mov eax, 99999`, because there's another branch target that jumps into that path of execution.  But as you say, that has nothing to do with execution continuing to the next instruction.)